# PHP condition based JSON output of a complex object

Tags: php, json

I have a complex PHP object with multiple levels. All objects in the tree implement JsonSerializable interface so the default encoding is working fine.

However, I want to generate different outputs depending on the logged-in user. There is price info deep inside the object and for simple users, I want to hide it from the JSON but for the admins I want it to be there.

For example:
In case of a normal user:
`{...{id:1, title: 'product1'}...}`

And for admin: `{...{id:1, title: 'product1', price: 100}...}`

I'm using PHP 7.4 with strong types.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Test data:

```
catalog : {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Catalog A',
    locations : [{
        id: 100,
        type: 'INTERNAL',
        boxes: [{
            id: 200,
            barcode: '1234',
            products: [{
                id: 500,
                title: 'Product1',
                price: 100
            }, {
                id: 501,
                title: 'Product2',
                price: 170
            }]
        },{
            id: 201,
            barcode: '5874',
            products: [{
                id: 600,
                title: 'ProductA',
                price: 70
            }, {
                id: 601,
                title: 'ProductB',
                price: 75
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Example PHP class:

```
class Product implements JsonSerializable {
    private ?int $id;
    private string $title;
    private int $price;

    ...

    public function jsonSerialize() {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your start dataset? Am I right when I say you want to show certain properties of this object based off the user?

Comment: Hard to say without more code, I would probably solve it by checking user type before writing the price into the object

Comment: @Wimanicesir: Yes, certain properties based on the user.

Comment: You will need two different models, one representing product with simpler data and another containing the extended information. Based on the role of a user, you'd then either construct the simpler and/or extended model.